# Creating an R Function to Stack Columns Using Ordinal Positions Obtained from match()

Tags: r, function, stack

I have two vectors `pre_t` and `pre_w`  containing the names of columns of a data farme `datos` I want to `stack()` in a new data frame `d`. To find the positions of these variables in the original data frame, I used the following code:

```
num_col_t <- match(pre_t, names(datos))
num_col_w <- match(pre_w, names(datos))
```

This code gives me the ordinal positions of the columns I want to  `stack()`
Then I `stack()`  my columns with

```
d<-cbind(datos[2],stack(datos[c(6,12,45,18,42,102,90,81,48,21,123,120,126,129,36,9,60,
                                51,57,27,132,78,69,15,108,39,24,117,93,87)]),
         stack(datos[c(7,13,46,19,43,103,91,82,49,22,124,121,127,130,37,10,61,52,58,28,
                       133,79,70,16,109,40,25,118,94,88)]))
```

Now, I want to create a function that can directly `stack()` the results from `num_col_t` and `num_col_w` without manually copying each number. I've attempted the following without success:

```
for (i in numeros_columnas_t){
  s_t<-stack(datos[[i]])
}
for (j in numeros_columnas_w){
  s_w<-stack(datos[[j]])
}
cbind(s_t,s_w)
```

I'd appreciate any help in creating an efficient function for this purpose.